# find a single element in an array of consecutive duplicate elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of elements where every element is repeated except a single element. Moreover all the repeated elements are consecutive to each other.

We need to find out the index of that single element.

Note:

1. array may not be sorted
2. expected time O(logn)
3. range of elements can
       be anything.

O(n) is trivial. but how can I figure out logn?
Gave a thought to bitwise operators also but nothing worked out.

Also, I am unable to make use of this statement in this question **all the repeated elements are consecutive to each other.**

```
Ex:  2 2 3 3 9 9 1 1 5 6 6
     output 5
```

Comment: If the array is not sorted, you cannot achieve this in less than O(n), because you absolutely have to know each element before you can give an answer. If it is sorted, there may be a shortcut available but I cannot think of it off-hand.

Comment: if the array is sorted then defintely we can use binary search, but in case of unsorted array, may be any other data structure can do it... any specific tree AVL,  red black etc..

Comment: Actually I missed the fact that repeated elements are always consecutive. In that case, it makes no difference whether it is sorted or not, but I still can't think of a better-than-O(n) solution.

Comment: Oh are they repeated exactly twice? If there can't be more than 2 of each item it becomes quite easy. Just do a binary search on the point where the differences switch from even indexes to odd indexes.

Comment: didn't understand, how can we apply binary search ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done in O(logn) by checking if `arr[2k] == arr[2k+1], k>=0` - if it is, then the distinct elementt is AFTER `2k+1`, if it's not - than it is before before `2k+1`.

This allows you to effectively trim half of the array at each step by checking the middle value, and recursing only on a problem half as big, getting it `O(logn)` overall.

Python code:

```
def findUnique(arr,l,r):
    if r-l < 2: 
        return (arr[l],l)
    mid = (r-l)/2 + l
    if mid % 2 != 0:
        flag = -1
    else:
        flag = 0
    if (mid == 0 or arr[mid-1] != arr[mid] ) and (mid == len(arr)-1 or arr[mid] != arr[mid+1] ):
        return (arr[mid],mid)
    if arr[mid+flag] == arr[mid+1+flag]:
        return findUnique(arr,mid,r)
    return findUnique(arr,l,mid)
```

Comment: that means it cannot be solved in any way in O(logn) if we don't know how many times do they repeat themselves?

Comment: @Prashant It can be done in O(logn+m) if the number of repetitions for all elements is `m>1`, and we don't need to need `m` in advance, just find out what's `m` (by going through the first `m+1` items), and repeat the same process with checking `arr[k*m]` and `arr[a*m + m-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each element is repeated exactly twice, except one, then it is easy.
The first answer is correct, just feel like I could elaborate a bit on it.

So, lets take your example array.

```
a = [2 2 3 3 9 9 1 1 5 6 6];
```

If *all* elements were paired, then you can take an even index and know for sure that the next element will be the same.

```
a[0] = 2;
a[1] = 2; //as well
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 3; //as well
```

General case:

```
a[k] = a[k+1] = x;
```

where k is even, and x is some value.

BUT, in your case, we know that there is one index that doesn't follow this rule.
in order to find it, we can use [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (just for reference), with a bit of extra computation in the middle.
We go somewhere in the middle, and grab an element with an even index.
If that elements' value equals to the next elements' value, then your *lonely* value is in the second part of the array, because the pairing wasn't broken yet.
If those values are not equal, then either your *lonely* value is in the first half OR you are at it (it is in the middle).

You will need to check couple elements before and after to make sure.

By cutting your array in half with each iteration, you will achieve O(logn) time.

Comment: The first answer is, without a doubt, correct.  I just felt like I could add some extra explanation. :)